# Passing an Array of Elements Properly

Tags: javascript

If what is input is wrong, I want it to highlight red. I tried the following:

Comment: It sounds to me like `//something not relevant` might be more relevant than you think. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong? Did you encounter any errors or get unexpected output?

Comment: i corrected my previous code @CollinD

Comment: what does `ltr.test` and `regex.test` make?

Comment: @NinaScholz they check if the input is a letter or regex ( i know i can us isNaN but i want to differentiate between the two

Comment: and where is `em_input` coming from?

Comment: @NinaScholz https://jsfiddle.net/zrL60Lhg/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use only one system to access the input fileds, either via form name and input name or with id and `document.getElementById`.

Then I suggest to use `id` and `name` attribute of `<input type="text">` with the same value.

For checking content and changing the style, I take the element and use an array with `id`.

```js
function check() {
    var regex = new RegExp(/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?()]/),
        ltr = /[a-zA-Z ]+/,
        inputs = ['nem', 'nef', 'rem', 'ref', 'ea', 'ver', 'kavm', 'kavf'],
        i,
        fehlerB = false,
        element;

    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        element = document.getElementById(inputs[i]);
        if (ltr.test(element.value) && !regex.test(element.value)) {
            element.style.border = '2px solid red'; // i suggest to use 2px, because
            fehlerB = true;                         // it renders better on displays
        }                                           // with sub pixel
    }
    return !fehlerB;
}
```

```html
<form name="inputform" id="inputform" onsubmit="return check()" action="">
    <input id="nem" name="nem">
    <input id="nef" name="nef">
    <input id="rem" name="rem">
    <input id="ref" name="ref">
    <input id="ea" name="ea">
    <input id="ver" name="ver">
    <input id="kavm" name="kavm">
    <input id="kavf" name="kavf">
    <input type="submit" onclick="return check()" />
</form>
```